# Prestahop api 1.7 update order webservice error

Tags: api, postman, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm triyng to update an order status & tranking number on prestashop 1.7.6.0 via webservice but if the new order status has to send email to customer I get error 500.
Cases:

1. new order status id 5 send email > error 500 (status changed, no mail sent, other changes like track nr ignored)
2. new order status id 4 doesn't send email > code 200 (all ok)

BUT if I try changing manually in back office to order status id 5 all is working, status changed and mail sent.

I do all my test on Postman as these information will be changed with a call from an external service for the management of shipment, how can I debug this problem?

End Point: [www.domain.ext/api/orders/10705](http://www.domain.ext/api/orders/10705)

xml sent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
    <id>10705</id>
    <id_address_delivery xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/addresses/11307">11307</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/addresses/11307">11307</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/carts/11918">11918</id_cart>
    <id_currency xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/currencies/2">2</id_currency>
    <id_lang xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/languages/2">2</id_lang>
    <id_customer xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/customers/10806">10806</id_customer>
    <id_carrier xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/carriers/5">5</id_carrier>
    <current_state xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/order_states/5">5</current_state>
    <module>codwfeeplus</module>
    <invoice_number>0</invoice_number>
    <invoice_date>2022-05-10 15:32:41</invoice_date>
    <delivery_number>9050</delivery_number>
    <delivery_date>2022-05-17 15:16:33</delivery_date>
    <valid>1</valid>
    <date_add>2022-05-10 15:32:40</date_add>
    <date_upd>2022-05-17 15:23:53</date_upd>
    <shipping_number notFilterable="true">1592222222</shipping_number>
    <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <secure_key>044248612d0019be079f165138d46e85</secure_key>
    <payment>CONTRASSEGNO</payment>
    <recyclable>0</recyclable>
    <gift>0</gift>
    <gift_message/>
    <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
    <total_discounts>0.000000</total_discounts>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl>0.000000</total_discounts_tax_incl>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl>0.000000</total_discounts_tax_excl>
    <total_paid>15.500000</total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl>15.500000</total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl>15.500000</total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real>15.500000</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>9.500000</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>9.500000</total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping>6.000000</total_shipping>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl>6.000000</total_shipping_tax_incl>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl>6.000000</total_shipping_tax_excl>
    <carrier_tax_rate>0.000</carrier_tax_rate>
    <total_wrapping>0.000000</total_wrapping>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl>0.000000</total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl>0.000000</total_wrapping_tax_excl>
    <round_mode>2</round_mode>
    <round_type>1</round_type>
    <conversion_rate>1.000000</conversion_rate>
    <reference>10705</reference>
<associations>
<order_rows nodeType="order_row" virtualEntity="true">
    <order_row>
    <id>10913</id>
    <product_id xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/products/203975">203975</product_id>
    <product_attribute_id>0</product_attribute_id>
    <product_quantity>1</product_quantity>
    <product_name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</product_name>
    <product_reference>12859</product_reference>
    <product_ean13/>
    <product_isbn/>
    <product_upc/>
    <product_price>10.000000</product_price>
    <id_customization xlink:href="https://www.domain.ext/api/customizations/0">0</id_customization>
    <unit_price_tax_incl>9.500000</unit_price_tax_incl>
    <unit_price_tax_excl>9.500000</unit_price_tax_excl>
    </order_row>
</order_rows>
</associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

Comment: Is this perhaps a multi language store? If so, check when testing if the mail template and all the mail variables are available in all languages.

Comment: No, single language.

Answer (score 0):

I found it's a Prestashop 1.7.6 WS bug

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/14842

Solved here https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/14899